# Trailing spaces pasted when using vim

Tags: vim

`TERM=xterm-256color`

When I cut and paste on the terminal, there are no trailing spaces in the output.  If I copy from the terminal and paste into vim, there are no trailing spaces in the paste.  When I use vim, with the molokai color scheme, whatever I copy and paste has trailing spaces.  What my mouse has highlighted, including blank space after the real lines, is pasted.  I did not have the problem before using the color scheme.  Can this be fixed without ditching the otherwise great color scheme?

Comment: Are you sure it's the fault of the colorscheme? Vim is supposed to include trailng spaces in copy/paste, or it's not doing its job (it's never safe for an application to assume it's okay to exclude data).

Comment: @Heptite - the spaces don't exist in the file.  They are "made up" by vim when I paste (the mouse highlight included blank space, and vim turned it into spaces on paste.)   I don't know why the color scheme would cause this, but I didn't have the problem before it.

Comment: My mistake. If you haven't already, you might want to do `:set mouse=a` and let VIm handle cut and paste within the terminal, instead of letting the terminal do it.

Comment: @Heptite - Thank you for the tip.  I get the same behavior after `:set mouse=a`

Comment: What does `:set list` show?

Comment: @Heptite - When I type `:set list` I see the content that I can copy and paste, with dollar signs right at the end of the lines (the character position next to the last character in the line).  So there's no empty space.

Comment: I'm stumped. Hopefully someone else can help.